# Envío y recepción de archivos por socket TCP

Tags: java, socket, tcp

Estoy intentando enviar un archivo por socket utilizando TCP.

El problema llega a la hora de leerlo, se queda en el while, pero no de manera infinita, sino que se queda como "dormido".

El código para enviar y recibir el archivo es el siguiente:

Enviar archivo:

```
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        os.flush();
```

Recibir archivo:

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        int bytesRead;

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(usuario.getId() + "_" + ruta.getTitulo() + ".gpx");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        output.close();
```

La única forma de conseguir que llegue a salir del while cuando lee es cerrando el socket desde el otro extremo, pero no quiero eso. ¿Qué podría hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer `os.close()` en el envío, haces un *EOF (fin de archivo)* y eso le avisa al receptor de que terminó el archivo, y recibe el tamaño de bytes `-1`. Solo así termina el `while`. No hay otra manera de terminar el envío.

Comment: Si hago os.close() me va a cerrar el stream para siempre y necesitaría volver a abrir el socket en la siguiente comunicación.

Comment: Solo una curiosidad ¿para qué necesitas terner el stream abierto? Los navegadores web funcionan así: abren un archivo, termina el envío y pide otro (sean img, js, css,html) Cada archivo son recibidos en conexiones / stream diferentes.

Comment: Porque lo utilizo varias veces par otras cosas, en el uso de una app que está en todo momento conectada con el servidor y no puedo perder la conexión

Comment: ¿y el que recibe, cómo va a saber que ya terminó de recibir todo el archivo?
Lo que puedes hacer - sugiero, aunque no es optimo - enviar un caracter especial, y en el receptor evalúas que ya llegó, y así cortas esa transmisión.

Comment: En principio la parte de envío, al hacer el write, debería de decirle cuándo ha terminado, tengo hecha una prueba en local que sí que funciona y aquí no me funciona y no sé por qué, está igual el código